# Android - Preference onCreateView attrs.getAttributeCount()

Tags: android

How do I get the "max" attribute during onCreateView()?
If I can get attrs.getAttributeCount() to work that would solve my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:title="@string/livewallpaper_settings"
        android:key="livewallpaper_settings"
    >
        <com.example.myapp.SeekBarPreference1
            android:persistent="true"
            android:key="keyItems"
            android:title="Items"
            android:defaultValue="50"
            android:max="200" />
        <com.example.myapp.SeekBarPreference1
            android:persistent="true"
            android:key="keyItemsTwo"
            android:title="Items Two"
            android:defaultValue="5"
            android:max="10" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is the simplified class. XmlPullParser does not return anything to parse.

```
    public final class SeekBarPreference1 extends Preference implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

        private static int _maxValue = 0;
        private int _currentValue = 0;
        private TextView _value;
        private SharedPreferences _preferences;

        public SeekBarPreference1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            _preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

            //
            // These values are correct
            //
            Log.d("PREFS", " ");
            Log.d("PREFS", "SeekBarPreference1");
            Log.d("PREFS", "Key: " + getKey());
            Log.d("PREFS", "AttrCount: " + attrs.getAttributeCount());
            Log.d("PREFS", "####");
        }

        @Override
        protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {

            XmlPullParser attrs = parent.getResources().getXml(R.xml.livewallpaper_settings);

            Log.d("PREFS", " ");
            Log.d("PREFS", "onCreateView");
            Log.d("PREFS", "Key: " + getKey()); // Correct key is output
            Log.d("PREFS", "AttrCount: " + attrs.getAttributeCount()); // -1
            Log.d("PREFS", "####");  

        }
}
```

Log output

```
SeekBarPreference1
Key: keyItems
AttrCount: 7
####

SeekBarPreference1
Key: keyItemsTwo
AttrCount: 7
####

onCreateView
Key: keyItems
AttrCount: -1
####

onCreateView
Key: keyItemsTwo
AttrCount: -1
####
```

It seems to me that if I can get the correct key, title, summery, etc. (from onCreateView) there should be a simple way to get other attributes.?

If I try and store the attributes from SeekBarPreference1(), they are lost as soon as onCreateView() is called.

Summery: get the attributes from the current "this" onCreateView();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it figured out.

```
public SeekBarPreference1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    _preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    // Save your shared prefs here
    // I saved the seekbar max && current value
    // Something like below
    for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
        if (attrs.getAttributeName(i).equals("max"))
            _preferences.edit().putString(getKey() +"Max", ""+ 
                    attrs.getAttributeValue(i)).commit();
    }
}
```

Then retrieve the data onCreateView()

```
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {

    // Retrieve the data
    // Now you will always have the correct data
    _maxValue = Integer.parseInt(_preferences.getString(getKey() +"Max", ""));

}
```

Now I can use the same class multiple times, finally...